# How to get the upload status with .net youtube API direct upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube, youtube-api

I have been trying to workout with youtubi API direct upload method, have been successful in uploading the video but the issue is some of the video's get rejected (Rejected (terms of use violation)) after uploading.

I need to find out a way to track them in webResponse, If I read the steram (readTOEnd()) XML

```
<app:control>
    <app:draft>yes</app:draft>
    <yt:state name='processing'/>
</app:control>
```

state name always shows 'processing'.
Please point me to right direction you have any idea/experiance about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
    WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse(); 
    // Obtain a 'Stream' object associated with the response object.
    Stream ReceiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

    Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

     // Pipe the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
     StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader( ReceiveStream, encode );
     Console.WriteLine("\nResponse stream received");
     Byte[] read = new Byte[256];

     int count = readStream.Read( read, 0, 256 );
     Console.WriteLine("HTML...\r\n");

     if (count > 0) 
     {
           Console.Write("Success Reading");
     }
```

Comment: Dont know what this code is supposed to do, I tried it, readStream.Read doesn't takes read (Char[]) as a parameter, it needs a byte[].

Comment: Thanks for taking out time on this, I have q quick question the code the you wrote about, return's int value if the video is successfully landed on you tube server that's it, It doesn't says weather it was approved for rejected because of some reason, right ???

Comment: I'am happy to help you Vishal, you can add all your code in try catch block, in order to capture exception if occured.